# Proper way to handle initializing an interface from view model

Tags: vb.net, mvvm

Working in vb.net here, but I'm sure C# applies

I have a view model, `BaseViewModel`, which has a list of child view models included, `ChildViewModel`.  The `ChildViewModel` maps back to `ChildClass`, and the `BaseViewModel` maps back to `BaseClass`.

All of these classes are protected by interfaces.

Lets say the user uses the UI to create a new `BaseViewModel`, and on it the user adds 2 `ChildViewModels`.  When the user clicks save, I have no trouble looping through these `ChildViewModels` and calling `UpdateModel` on each one in order to map the properties back to my base class.  However, when my list of `ChildClass`'s on the `BaseClass` is not large enough to new `ChildViewModels`, I get a out of range exception.

The `UpdateModel` of the `BaseViewModel`

```
Friend Sub UpdateModel(bc as BaseClass)
    For Each item in ListOfChildViewModels
        Dim updateMe = bc.ListOfChildClasses.FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Id = role.Id)
        If updateMe Is Nothing Or role.Id = 0 Then
            ''Add a new role
        Else
            item.UpdateModel(bc.ListOfChildClasses)
    Next
End Sub
```

Who can explain what I am doing wrong and how I can Add a new role here